# Selecting multiple elements from list of matrix that match elements of list of vector

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have two variables, one is a list of matrices and the other is a list of vectors.

people: `load("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22681355/a.Rdata")`

mat: `load("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22681355/b.Rdata")`

I would like to go from `[[1]]` to `[[99]]` along the elements in `people` and select the rows in `mat` where the first column of `mat` matches `people` and return the second column of `mat`.

I tried:

```
lapply(seq_along(people), function(i) mat[mat[,1,i] == 
    people[i], 2, i])
```

However this cannot handle the fact that sometimes there is only 1 matching entry while in other cases there can be 2 or three matching entries.

Can someone help with modifying my code?

Small example:

People:

```
[[1]]
[1] 34 56 7
[[2]]
[1] 13 93
[[3]]
[1] 42
```

Mat

```
,,1
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 34   **2**    1
[2,] 56   **2**    1
[3,] 7    **2**    2

,,2
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 9    2    1
[2,] 13   **2**    1
[3,] 71   2    2

,,3
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 90   2    1
[2,] 1    2    1
[3,] 42   **2**    2
```

The output would be:

Comment: I can't access your data using your links

Comment: Please `dput` a _small_ sample of your data.

Comment: @user20650 you mean you can't open it in R or is the link broken? the link works here.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example. Once you remove the files from your dropbox folder/account, this question will be handicapped.

Comment: I made a small example where I have in bold the output that should be returned.

Comment: Sorry - my error - links work. I was having difficulty with the 's' (secure) of https.

Comment: Trying to understand why the element [2,2,2] gets returned.  It's corresponding first-column value (13) is in the second position, whereas the 13 in people[[2] is in the first position. Maybe you want to replace the `==` with `%in%` ?

Comment: The [[x]] in People should correspond to the ,,x in Mat. So in the first case 34,56,7 are all in Mat so all of the rows are selected. From the second ,,2 of Mat only 13 is present so only that row is selected, etc. does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is pulling out what you want. From your comment i am matching the elements of people[1] with mat[,,1], people[2] with mat[,,2] and so on and returning the value in the second column of mat if there id a match.

I have used the first 3 values from your people and mat Rdata.

```
# Reduce problem
# mat <- mat[,,1:3]
#people <- people[1:3]

# Data
mat <- structure(c(82, 59, 6, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 17, 51, 18, 1, 2, 1, 
               1, 2, 1, 31, 26, 40, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), .Dim = c(3L, 3L, 3L))

people <- list(6, 51, c(31, 26, 40))


l <- lapply(seq(people), function(x) {
            lapply(people[x] , function(z) {
                   mat[,,x][,2][match(z, mat[,,x][,1])]
       })})


#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# output
R> mat
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   82    1    1
[2,]   59    1    1
[3,]    6    2    2

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   17    1    1
[2,]   51    2    2
[3,]   18    1    1

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   31    1    1
[2,]   26    1    1
[3,]   40    1    1

R> people
[[1]]
[1] 6

[[2]]
[1] 51

[[3]]
[1] 31 26 40

R> l
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 2


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 2


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 1 1 1
```